# Identify the names of stored procedures that are being executed based on the tables that they interact with

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-profiler

I have a scenario where there are multiple stored procedures that insert records into the same table however at least 2 of these procedures are not inserting data into a specific field when they insert new records.

I want to identify the names of the stored procedures that are being executed based on the name of the table that they are inserting records into. From here I can place debug points where these stored procs are called and figure out which ones are being given the data to write to this field.

I have tried using SQL Profiler and selected Audit Schema Object Access Event and filtered by ObjectName like %Table_Name% and this captures the interactions with the table but does not give me the stored procedure names.

Is there a way to filter the traces based on the name of an affected table and see the stored procedure name that was interacting with this table?

Comment: Not really...at least reliably. A procedure could affect any number of tables. There could be synonyms involved which would make that more challenging. There could be dynamic sql which would make it nearly (or even completely) impossible. But you could use sql search, a free product from redgate to search for a given table name.

Comment: If you can modify the procedures and the table structure, you could add a "modifying_stored_procedure" field to the target table, and then update each stored procedure to "sign its work".  A bit of a brute force approach, but it might be quicker than spelunking in profiler traces.

Comment: If the field should not allow NULLs, you should put a constraint on the field.